# Deserializing JSON gives NullReferenceException was unhandled

Tags: c#, json

I have a JSON response from my php upload in a free hosting site that will output the following:

```
{"cart":[{"cardno":"1111111111","product_id":"10000104","name":"Hotsilog","quantity":"1","price":"35","category":"breakfast"},{"cardno":"1111111111","product_id":"10000107","name":"Champorado","quantity":"1","price":"15","category":"breakfast"}]}
```

and I have this C# form to test if im deserializing it properly:

```
public class Costing
{
    public List<CustomerCosting> costing { get; set; }
}

public class CustomerCosting
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string cardno { get; set; }
    public string product_id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string quantity { get; set; }
    public string price { get; set; }
    public string category { get; set; }
}

private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    NameValueCollection userInfo = new NameValueCollection();
    userInfo.Add("cardno", textBox6.Text);
    byte[] uploadVal = client.UploadValues("http://eallowance.x10host.com/v1/getCart.php", "POST", userInfo);
    string getResponse = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(uploadVal);

    richTextBox1.Text = getResponse.ToString();
    Costing customerCosting = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Costing>(getResponse);

    foreach (var item in customerCosting.costing)
    {
        listView1.Items.Add("name: {3}", item.name);
    }
}
```

Everything is good up to the `richTextBox1.Text = getResponse.ToString();` part. It is there to test if im getting the response properly. But when it enters the foreach part, it crash and gives a `NullReferenceException`. The `listView1.Items.Add` part is just to test if it got deserialized. What I will do for the foreach part is to upload each row into my database.

Comment: Well, is it null?

Comment: Use http://json2csharp.com/ to correct your model.  In the JSON the root object's only property is named `"cart"` not `"costing"`.

Comment: i think so, no items is added in listView

Comment: The name of the property in the JSON that contains the list is `cart` not `costing`  as you attempt to use in your `Costing` type. Change the property to `public List<CustomerCosting> cart { get; set; }` and it will work.

Comment: I think that `customerCosting` object is null and you are trying to access a property on a null object.
Always precheck an object before using. Also, your serialized content has `cart` and deserializer has no information about it and was not able to build\deserialize `Costing` object. Provide a mapping or an annotation for the same.
I'll also suggest that Create Costing object and serialize it to see how Costing gets serialized.